# Intellij: Gradle dependency not found

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

How would I solve this problem where the dependency can't be found? I have the library on my PC, I just don't know how to import it into my project.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to configure it in your Gradle dependencies and then hit the Gradle refresh button.

Comment: @cjstehno how do I configure my gradle dependencies? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Your build.gradle file -- sounds like you have some reading to do: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: @cjstehno I added this to my build.gradle http://i.imgur.com/hehzv7M.png but I still have no idea how to remove the faulty lib from the list.

Comment: If you are trying to remove the dependency and you did not explicitly add it, it's probably being brought in by one of your explicit dependencies.. you can run `gradle dependencies` to see which libraries bring in what and then you can exclude the transitive dependencies that you don't want.

Comment: Actually, from looking at the image you shared... you are explicitly bringing in that dependency, so just remove that line and it should go away. Also, why dont they have "groups"?