# IntelliJ IDEA unable to resolve fine working gradle dependency

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, bukkit

I'm currently working on a Kotlin project with Gradle ([source code here](https://github.com/axelrindle/Broadcaster-Plugin)). It's a Bukkit plugin which depends on a library I maintain ([library source code here](https://github.com/axelrindle/PocketKnife/)). When running `./gradlew assemble` in a terminal, everything works fine and the build succeeds (*log below*).

```
$ ./gradlew assemble --console plain

> Task :compileKotlin
w: Some JAR files in the classpath have the Kotlin Runtime library bundled into them. This may cause difficult to debug problems if there's a different version of the Kotlin Runtime library in the classpath. Consider removing these libraries from the classpath
w: /home/axel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.axelrindle/PocketKnife/v1.3.0/b2303013bfd8e21c419f1d640ef374afc48e86af/PocketKnife-v1.3.0.jar: Library has Kotlin runtime bundled into it

> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

But when working in IDEA, my library is the only one the IDE fails to resolve for whatever reason.

I've already tried the following steps:

- Delete gradle/idea caches (`~/.gradle/caches`;`.idea`)
- Reinstall IDEA
- Delete IDEA config directory (`.IdeaIC2019.1`)
- Reimport the project in IDEA

I've already read the following questions/answers, but none of them worked:

- [Getting Gradle dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694442/getting-gradle-dependencies-in-intellij-idea-using-gradle-build)
- [Unable to resolve dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155495/unable-to-resolve-dependencies-in-intellij-idea-2018-1)
- [Gradle dependencies not working in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013495/gradle-dependencies-not-working-in-intellij)
- [IntelliJ won't recognize some imports from gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308453/intellij-wont-recognize-some-imports-from-gradle-project)
- [Intellij: Gradle dependency not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653220/intellij-gradle-dependency-not-found)

Also, my `idea.log` can be found here: https://pastebin.com/0Z5b3Wdp

Last but not least some version information:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.18.0-21-generic
```

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          12.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 12.0.1+12)
OS:           Linux 4.18.0-21-generic amd64
```

Comment: @Anatolii As i mentioned, i already tried deleting the whole `.idea` directory and reimporting afterwards. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Axel I just cloned your repository and successfully executed build->assemble within IntelliJ.
Could you try to clone your repository in another directory and try it again?

Comment: @Axel Also can you provide your idea.log? Within IntelliJ do Help -> Show Log in Explorer

Comment: @hce if you cloned the repository I linked above, I think I expressed myself wrong. The linked repository is the library, not the actual project.

Comment: @Axel Pls. provide your actual project or a minimal sample demonstrating the issue and provide your idea.log too.

Comment: @hce I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of failed troubleshooting, I found out what the problem was. My library contained the bundled kotlin runtime, which was causing impossible to debug resolving issues with IDEA. I split up the project into multiple subprojects, where the actual api dependency does not bundle the kotlin runtime. This fixed my issues.

Comment: I lost 2 days with the same problem and solution. I wish I saw your answer sooner! I built a JAR and bundled Kotlin in it, whilst also having Kotlin in my project already. It gave no error message but wouldn't import any dependencies. So weird

Answer (score 2):

I just cloned your repository from https://github.com/axelrindle/Broadcaster-Plugin

In your **build.gradle** file you are referencing version **1.2.2** of your PocketKnife artefact, which does not exist in your GitHub. If you use an existing version like **1.2.1** IntelliJ can resolve the dependency.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right. This is invalid, but I'm locally working with 1.3.0 already, I just didn't push the changes yet. Nevertheless thank you very much for your kind support!