# Gradle project builds successfully but IntelliJ cannot resolve references

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Every usage of the following Kotlin library compiles and can be used, but IntelliJ's autocomplete (and perhaps others) cannot resolve the references.
https://gitlab.com/7Hazard/altv-kotlin

I am using it as a dependency via JitPack: https://jitpack.io/#com.gitlab.7Hazard/altv-kotlin
JDK 11, Gradle 6.3 (wrapper)

The gradle project builds fine but just autocompletion is broken. Other dependencies like kotlinx.coroutines work fine.

[image: IntelliJ's linter error]

It `altv-kotlin` is a fatjar and even includes the sources in the jar: https://gitlab.com/7Hazard/altv-kotlin/-/blob/master/build.gradle#L53
It in turn uses a java dependency, so `altv-kotlin` uses some Java and the end fatjar includes both Kotlin and Java sources if that makes a difference.

Could it be that the source are not being put in the JAR correctly for some reason? I couldn't even get IDEA to decompile the references for autocompletion. I have a strong feeling this is an issue tied to `altv-kotlin` library specifically, and not any of my environment setup.

I've tried to delete the .idea folder, Invalidate Caches / Restart, update Kotlin plugin for both IDEA and gradle projects and even updated IDEA from 2018 to 2020 with no avail whatsoever.
I tried these answers as well but did not solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56619181/8122837
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/8122837
I also noticed the warning about Kotlin Runtime being bundled with the library, but even without it being bundled in it IDEA complains.

Comment: I saw these aswell but didn't help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56619181/8122837 https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/8122837

Comment: Does this answer your question? `File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu No, I stated in the post that I already tried that in several ways

Comment: Does it work with older Gradle version (e.g. 5.1)?

Comment: @y.bedrov That's what I used before upgrading

Comment: Am I got you right that switching to older Gradle version fixes the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov I switched as far down to 4.9 (cause of dep limits) and it IDEA autocomplete still didn't work. Compiled fine like always though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, locally I seem to have resolved the issue by recreating the project and copying the sources into there. Seems to have worked, why I don't know.
However, when using the remote dependency from JitPack, because I was including all the classfiles in the JAR to have it be a fatjar.

```
jar {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
}
```

Ever since I removed that line from the `jar` task, IntelliJ IDEA was able to resolve the references normally.